# How to prioritze returning an object from a list

Tags: python

I have a list of objects returning boolean values like this

```
badges = [{"is_staff": self.sender.is_staff},
                  {"is_vendor": self.sender.is_vendor}, {"is_trader": self.sender.is_trader}]

# or we can write this like that; 
badges = [{"is_staff": True}, {"is_vendor": False}, {"is_trader": True}]
```

I want to return the user badge with this priority;
is_staff has the highest priority, then vendor and then trader.

If the user has all badges then I want to return only the badge for is_staff as a string value to = 'staff' as it has the highest priority.

like

```
badge = 'staff'
```

I have this function to work with. but don't find a way to return the value that I wanted.

```
@property
def badge(self):
    "Returns the user's designation if the user is Staff, Vendor, Trader."
    badges = [{"is_staff": self.sender.is_staff},
              {"is_vendor": self.sender.is_vendor}, {"is_trader": self.sender.is_trader}]
    badge = ''
    # need help there to find the value on the basis of badges 
    return badge
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason that `badges` is a list of dictionaries rather than just being a dictionary?

Comment: No, we can modify it , it's not mandatory

Comment: But one user can have all of these badges in boolean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of a list of dictionaries, which is needlessly unwieldy, track your `badges` as a dictionary that maps each badge name to its value.

In Python 3, dictionaries preserve order based on how you define the keys, so you can define the keys in order of priority:

```
>>> badges = {"staff": False, "vendor": True, "trader": True}
```

and then simply pick the first key with a true value:

```
>>> next(b for b, v in badges.items() if v)
'vendor'
```